# How to manage different types of data in the base class?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, design-patterns

My goal is to separate data from various implementations. I don't want my things to know what actual subclass it is they are working with, either way around. To make things perform only a single task with minimal information.

I'll throw some [code](http://www.cpp.sh/6yvbc) in your eyes first.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class Model
{
    public:
    
    virtual bool set(int p_attrId, int p_value) {return false;}; 
    virtual bool get(int p_attrId, int & p_value) const {return false;};

};

class Derived: public Model
{
    static constexpr int c_classId = 1;
    int value = 1;
    public:
    
    enum EAttrs
    {
        eAttr1 = c_classId * 1000
    };
    
    virtual bool set(int p_attrId, int p_value) override
    {
        switch(p_attrId)
        {
            case eAttr1:
                value = p_value;
                return true;
            
            default:
                return Model::set(p_attrId, p_value);
        }
    }

    virtual bool get(int p_attrId, int & p_value) const override
    {
        switch(p_attrId)
        {
            case eAttr1:
                p_value = value;
                return true;
            
            default:
                return Model::get(p_attrId, p_value);
        }
    }
};

// GuiTextBoxComponent.h

// no includes to any class derived from model

class GuiTextBoxComponent
{
        std::weak_ptr<Model> m_model;
        int m_attrId;
    public:
        void draw()
        {
            auto locked = m_model.lock();
            if(locked)
            {
                int value;
                bool result = locked->get(m_attrId, value);
                if(!result)
                {
                    std::cout << "Failed to get attribute " << m_attrId << "\n";
                    return;
                }
            
                std::cout << "AttrID: " << m_attrId << " Value: " << value << "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Model is dead\n";
            }
        }
        
        void setSource(std::weak_ptr<Model> p_model, int p_attrId)
        {
            m_model = p_model;
            m_attrId = p_attrId;
        }
};


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Model> model (new Derived);
    GuiTextBoxComponent textbox;
    textbox.setSource(model, Derived::eAttr1);
    textbox.draw();
}
```

The motivation behind this is acquisition of all data from a single interface.
I need to be able to add functionality like the GuiTextBoxComponent, without `#include "Derived1.h"` in its header.

The challenge with this design is that the Model interface needs to implement all types required from anywhere in the program.

How would you extend the types provided?

Is there some other design that could be used to achieve similar results?

Comment: Why not checking one of the SOLID principles: [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)?

Comment: Are you ever accessing those methods through a pointer or reference to `Model`? If not, you could use a CRTP base, i.e. static instead of dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: It's in the example. A pointer to Model should suffice in all cases.

Comment: IMHO, you're asking the wrong question, in other words this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why should `Model` provide an interface that is only needed by one (or even none) of all of its actual/potential derived classes? `Model` should only care about things that are specific to a *generic model*, not to a *specific model* only.

Comment: Take the classical `shape` example. A `shape` can have a `virtual void draw() const`, but a `virtual double diameter() const` makes no sense. In other words, the *acquisition of all data from a single interface* is a bad idea.

Comment: I updated the example. Notice how the `printInt` function doesn't care which subclass of `Model` is used. It can print any int from any model subclass.

Comment: but it can only print `int`s.

Comment: I think your question is still unclear. You should provide an example of what you are aiming at.

Comment: I see that It failed to demonstrate the point I was trying to make.

Comment: Nice downvotes, care to explain what my question is missing first? It took a while to write a more complete example.

Comment: @Walter The diameter would in my case be just a number somewhere. Sure, you can ask for a diameter from any Model derived class but most would just return false to indicate that the value is not available from this implementation.

Comment: You might use `std::any` instead of your `int`.. but then you might also know the expected type to use it...

Comment: @Jarod42 I was unaware of std::any, sounds interesting. I'll look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I think this is an XY problem but here is how you can beautify your code a bit. First, I implemented two interfaces: `Getter` and `Setter` like:

```cpp
enum class EAttrs {
    eAttr1
};

template <typename GetterImpl>
struct Getter {
    bool get(EAttrs const attrId, int& value) {
        switch (attrId) {
        case EAttrs::eAttr1:
            return static_cast<GetterImpl*>(this)->get(value);
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
};

template <typename SetterImpl>
struct Setter {
    bool set(EAttrs const attrId, int value) {
        switch (attrId) {
        case EAttrs::eAttr1:
            return static_cast<SetterImpl*>(this)->set(value);
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Here I used CRTP, i.e. static polymorphism. Then implementation of your derived classes is a bit simpler:

```cpp
class Derived1 : public Getter<Derived1>, Setter<Derived1> {
    int value = 1;
public:    
    bool set(int p_value) {
        value = p_value;
        return true;
    }

    bool get(int & p_value) {
        p_value = value;
        return true;
    }
};

class Derived2 : public Getter<Derived1>, Setter<Derived1> {
    int value = 2;
public:
    bool set(int p_value) {
        value = p_value;
        return true;
    }

    bool get(int & p_value) {
        p_value = value;
        return true;
    }
};
```

Finally, since we were using CRTP, there is no need for creating `std::unique_ptr`. Code that's using above classes could look like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void printInt(Getter<T>& model, EAttrs p_attrId) {
    int value;
    bool result = model.get(p_attrId, value);
    if (!result)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to get attribute " << static_cast<int>(p_attrId) << "\n";
        return;
    }
    
    std::cout << "AttrID: " << static_cast<int>(p_attrId) << " Value: " << value << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Derived1 derived1;
    Derived2 derived2;
    
    printInt(derived1, EAttrs::eAttr1);
    printInt(derived2, EAttrs::eAttr1);
}
```

Check out the [DEMO](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRAAOTqQAOqBYXVaPUMTQV9/NTobO0cjFzcANi8lFUjaBgJmYgJg41NzFMxVQIysgmiHZ1cPZMzs3NDasorY%2BJAkgEpFVANiZA4AcgB6IYBqbAAPZiNvdlHvYlRgYmnxAAYAQSkAZltkQyxR8W2ddQUCYkxV7ex1rcld2n2DQ%2BOdc%2BJbYGPbzbutYyjfbMBQKcYbAgXMHiADssk2o0Ro0wEIunDusIAIsd4VtNgRMDNhASjicCABPbxaaaYUYAcUwkNcAEkiT87h8DKp6YyCcQjnC7kjRk5UPpRsBGRBsKjiGC0LRzqNmJDiMz0KRRrYCFIEqMAG5sAyYDoC3HC4UKADuhGQCFGEBVF3Vpth5otiJYSnBqoUIBAKNVnBAQo9FsuBF6tFG5xVeGQAH0vTqTgymWqiQAqH4QAgIPAKDoAWh%2BkoIEENhhNONDHqwVGYBlYBBDCLDwojUdGDdYShrbY9WNrAuxfxh2O2uLuBKJKtpbwpVNoNNGDF5LLZNw5Fy5BFX6/5buHovFSnLMt9QLoSqdao1WvoBqNJrNw8tNoIdodt5dr4HFq9WkLyhf1AzRVsNnbDtGS7WM1ETZM3jXdNWVmbMblzfNCxLG4zwrZ8On7SCw3rRtmwgqCkU7Yhox7PtJzfJEh3/ZitnHIi7mBUFRkxVw8H1TB0E4UYQHmAwnFYeMeXTN5eM%2BAShJ%2BTVkL5WS%2BIU9Ebj/YjEW1J8q1JTFRk03FvHEyTkFEpj/xPVgYylPTvATStjVdQV/2FFz522IynK8oj22o6Md0wAKmPYv4bLFOyywgPTdXmZyCO09s/OfQz9ONMKPSC0YQuykcMXYhjIo2LiwTk/jBMkESxIkqS01Uk5Ko0pT9xk5r1MEzTsBSpE9K8jLJCIsz6ss49ovs8tHKSqs3PdD1BuOXzZqykqdPDGCaLy4g1oWwrSuFWyJQcx8ErSua%2Bo9C7jQy/z1sCrbgt20KHvC0c2InKd8UJWY51JHRF2pIxaQAFXZTZ9VQPB0HmT56GZegIEa1w3nBrdJD1IwMGUTVgLlRKf3QebhwG58CuOy4FCbPdltGbGsFYAA6WKnKJzUvMIt7dKoB0wDAKmacIlj3I2y0CHQf00AMWmTjeI5JEkAAxZg8HYWGiBOvdbzwJwZfnRWAfluD4yTEEU1OegczZ1VfzeeWpGGgBWHRaEdgroMjGiCtY4Vh3OSWUB6WWdAdxXZWZTFRMdo2ThjTJ4LN843m1a2EyJ105bjmOADVn2jw37bjpas50BXndd931tYu49KMVXaAgYW2P2lrutGLB5O6gq2/QGrO6qvuff/BZtUR8sB40vHZT9ANZU4Ln9tHhGkcn6rp99UD58XoqPoGLpWBAAYnYGUhTAGNZT9QI/Q5kOQYx6PoDe2ThT5bC/966ABrEAnfcJmEjcEVgAThhAkJ2axODbDWE7J2Qgj7cFPufS%2BpBr4DFPn6NYpB36Xy6HAWAMBEBBxmGrVw5BKBoBIewNwwJRCcE4GsLBVA1Z8j9BAJwR8UFOFsFkcknDT6UJBvQAA8rQVgfCP6kCwPXUQ7B%2BFSLwJcYoAk/SSMwBMIo%2Bt5HamUPIySTgVjEHJHoLAR9X7YM%2BEYMx%2B9SA0HoEwNgHAeD8EEMIUQKA5ByCELrP0kAuioG8GkVRRYiwB2WhIO%2BMhOAwgwcoIoaRNDaAaKYLwlgWhVDcF4cIAQ6DJLCH4HJtB0lxGqMkOJxQ6ClHqPoPIghCgVPSHUcothKglMyYoJpeSmjZGKW0Be3Rej9C4AfI%2BJ8z7yLQRMdwCQiyAKBG44AxlOBMzWCsh0uBCAkAVi/TUegqGuG2QvUYt9ZAyDfvwjo39f5YMPgMRBpArEQPGZItBGCQBYJwTY/BRDg5mQIOQiAlDvCkPaYJTZ7S7GMBYHI5xVoVjeAufA4%2BSCJlHx2MJD89opkzLmbQxZ9CVkrPOR/S5pAEBXE7pQEZdzT6PKwcgq%2BR83kfIuVc7gyzthOxhDCNYDxuDAOmcA7gcDbnbBRS8pl2DWVIskOKlBrypUkq6AJOUgQQDcCAA%3D%3D%3D).

**P.S.** Note the usage of `enum class` instead of plain `enum`.

Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ntraj80qN2k&t=2939s&ab_channel=CppCon) CppCon's talk about Solid principles. Your code might be a good example to apply those principles to.

Comment: I was trying to make a point which was apparently not clear from my code. I'd like to separate any classes using the derived types from said derived types. Why write any of the code I did if that was not the goal?

Comment: @0xbaadf00d i must admit i don't understand what you are saying, sorry :( if you can be a bit clearer please.

Comment: I'd like to separate GUI components from data for example. I don't want to include Derived1.h from GuiTextBox.h. I tried to illustrate this by adding some sample code.

Comment: This always happens to me. I try to the best of my ability to write a complex question, people don't understand it and downvote it. I'm so done with trying to get any help from this site.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d I think that your example is too big now, try decreasing its size

Comment: There can't really think of any way to make it any shorter without losing key points